# Чтение файлов Визио (.vsd)

Tags: python, visio

Как можно прочитать визио файл? Задача такова: в визио нарисована некая схема - квадратики, кружочки и т.д. Каждый элемент подписан, может быть связан соединительной линией с другим элементом и т.д. Мне нужно прочитать это и преобразовать в некий файл формата .txt

Пытался прочитать его как и текстовый документ python-ом, только с параметром rb. Получил следующее (это лишь одна строка из 7700):

```
b'7\x0f!`\xeb\xf1\x82eQ\xd50."\x0e\x0c$7\x10&\x11\x00\x7fCommand\xf2\x147\x00\x00Gk0]\x11\x01+eQ\xfe\x13!\x00\x00\x18\x00Lis\x84\x1e"S!\xd4\xe0\xfcs/\x85/\x97/\x00\x07`\x01\x01\xad"r\x1f\x03\x8f\x15\x8f\xa8[A\x17\xec\xf0[!\xbe_O\x8f\xeb\xf1\'ePAh+6\xf4?\x85\x8f\x97\x8f*M\x1a;\x8f\x04\xcc\x8f\xe8\xf4)gOyO\n'
```

Есть где-либо документация, что это за кодировка? Или же другой, более гуманный способ прочитать .vsd?

Comment: Какая-то кодировка, только в бинарном виде. Попробуйте прочитать без параметра 'b'.

Comment: Поделитесь, пожалуйста, как Вы планируете преобразовывать изображения в формат txt?

Comment: @Эникейщик без параметра b он не может прочитать, даже если указать encode = UTF-8. В cp1251 тоже ошибка. В обоих случаях не знает того или иного символа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> что это за кодировка?

VSD является проприоретарным (закрытым) **бинарным** файловым форматом, который используется во всех старых версиях Visio.

> Есть где-либо документация

Соответственно - у Билли спрашивайте :-)

> более гуманный способ

Если у вас есть такая возможность, загрузите файл *.vsd в Вашу Visio  Standard / Professional / Pro и экспортируйте в формате VDX / VSDX / VSDM. Это текстовые файлы в формате XML. С ними уже что-то можно попытаться сделать, не спрашивая разрешения у Билли :-)

Comment: большое спасибо, формат XML уже более менее читабельный, логику можно найти.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visio умеет конвертировать свои диаграммы в xml,  этот xml если нужно можно с помощью xslt трансформировать в SVG формат

Comment: большое спасибо, ваша помощь аналогична ответу Sergey.

Answer (score 0):

Для просмотра данного файла можно использовать Microsoft Visio Viewer

Файл VSD можно конвертировать онлайн в PDF

Информация [VSD](https://www.azfiles.ru/extension/vsd.html)